# Menu com os temas

Tags: html, css

Estou com uma pequena dificuldade.

Tenho um menu em html e css e quero colocar da seguinte maneira.

Texto -  texto  -  Logotipo -  texto -  texto

Html:

```
 <div id="nav">
        <ul>        
            <li><span class="Email" ></span><a href="#"> EMail </a></li>
            <li><span class="Contactos" ></span><a href="#"> Contactos </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Multimedia </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Documentos </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 #nav { Width: 100%; background:#CCC; Margin:0px; Float:left;}
 #nav ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; width:100%; float:left; }
 #nav ul li { float: left; Font: 16px arial; }
 #nav ul li a { color:#888; text-decoration:none; padding:20px; display:block; }
 #nav ul li:hover {background: #666}
 #nav ul li .Email { background: url(image/1-email.png) no-repeat center; float: left; width: 100%; padding: 30px 0; margin-bottom: 15px; }
 #nav ul li .Contactos { background: url(image/2-contactos.png) no-repeat center; float: left; width: 100%; padding: 30px 0; margin-bottom: 15px; }
 #nav ul li .Multimedia { background: url(); float: left; width: 100%; }
 #nav ul li .Documentos { background: url(); float: left; width: 100%; }
```

Como consigo colocar os o texto Multimedia e Documentos para o lado direito pois preciso de espaço entre os textos para colocar logo.

http://jsfiddle.net/w27La83z/

Comment: Coloque seu código no http:/jsfiddle.net/ e edite seu POST, para podermos ajuda-lo melhor.

Comment: Obrigado, Não me lembrei desse pormenor . Já actualizei a minha pergunta com o jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá!

Tente fazer assim:

```css
#nav { width: 100%; background:#CCC; margin:0px; Float:left;}
#nav ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; width:100%; float:left; height: 65px }
#nav ul li { float: left; font: 16px arial; width: 20%; line-height: 65px;}
#nav ul li.logo > img {padding-left: 40px}
#nav ul li a { color:#888; text-decoration:none; display:block; height: 100%; background: no-repeat 5px center; padding-left: 40px;}
#nav ul li.email a {background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/20-web2_0-icons-pencil/24/gmail-pencil.png); }

#nav ul li.contactos a {background-image: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Futurosoft%20Icons%200.5.2/32x32/actions/kontact_contacts.png); }

#nav ul li.multimidia a {background-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/tango-icon-library/48/audio-x-generic-24.png); }

#nav ul li.documentos a {background-image: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698381-icon-72-documents-24.png); }

#nav ul li img {width: 64px; height: 64px;}
#nav ul li:hover a {background-color: #666; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>        
    <li class="email"><a href="#"> E-mail </a></li>
    <li class="contactos"><a href="#"> Contatos </a></li>
    <li class="logo"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-8/128/Chrome.png"/></li>
    <li class="multimidia"><a href="#"> Multimídia </a></li>
    <li class="documentos"><a href="#"> Documentos </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## UPDATE

Inseri imagens nos link.

Comment: Dá para controlar o tamanho dos botoes ?

Comment: Como assim 'controlar o tamanho dos botoes', não entendi =)?

Comment: Está a ver quando passamos o rato por cima por exemplo do email? o tamanho desse retangulo. 
Coloquei uns icones por cima do email e contactos mas desapareceram.

Comment: Atualizei minha responsta, @ChrisAdler. Seria isso?

Comment: SIm, para utilizar o padding como consigo chamar o texto e imagem ao mesmo tempo? usei o padding e so move a imagem

Comment: @ChrisAdler, você poderá aplicar o `padding` na sua `li`. Lembrando que a largura da `li` é relativa, portanto é interessante que o `padding` também seja relativo. Para que não haja quebras, o ideal é a soma dos valores do atributo 'width' com o do atributo `padding` deve ser igual à largura atual da `li`. Simplificando, atualmente a `li` possui a largura de 20%, se desejar um `padding` de 2%, a largura da `li` deverá ser `18%`

Comment: e dá para mover para a posição que quero colocando os valores? Ou so dá mesmo dessa forma?

Comment: Você diz utilizar valores absolutos, @ChrisAdler? da sim, é completamente possível. Se quiser, edito minha resposta e deixo o menu com valores absolutos pra você ter uma idéia melhor.

Comment: Se conseguir me explicar agradecia.

Comment: Trocar as medidas e % por px, por exemplo.

Comment: já consegui controlar tudo. Obrigado. So uma ultima coisa. Consigo editar o tamanho do hover? Quando passo o rato por cima ele fica um retangulo muito grande

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p9urLq0h/ consegue me explicar porque o cinzento nao esta no topo?

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta.

Comment: Tá a ver a barra cinzenta onde esta o menu? Não a consigo puxar para cima. Depois a outra duvida é em relação ao passar o rato por cima dos email por exemplo fica um retangulo cizento mais escuro muito grande

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso, eu faria assim,

```
 <ul id="esquerda">        
        <li><a href="#">email</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contactos</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="logo"> Logo</div>

        <ul id="direita">
            <li><a href="#">multimedia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">documentos</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

E o CSS:

```
#nav{
width:100%;
height:100px;
border:1px solid red;
}
#esquerda{
list-style:none;
float:left;
width:30%;
}
#logo{
float:left;
width:30%;
height:100px;
border:1px solid red;
}
#direita{
float:left;
width:30%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assim como o cara disse, existem diversas maneiras de se fazer

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
        <ul>        
            <li><span class="Email" ></span><a href="#"> EMail </a></li>
            <li><span class="Contactos" ></span><a href="#"> Contactos </a></li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"/>
            <li><a href="#"> Multimedia </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Documentos </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav { Width: 100%; background:#CCC; Margin:0px; Float:left; display:inline-flex;}
#nav ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; width:100%; display:inline-flex; }
#nav ul li { float: left; Font: 16px arial; }
#nav ul li a { color:#888; text-decoration:none; padding:20px; display:block; }
#nav ul li:hover {background: #666}
#nav ul li .Webmail { background: url(image/1-email.png) no-repeat center;  width: 100%; padding: 30px 0; margin-bottom: 15px; }
#nav ul li .Contactos { background: url(image/2-contactos.png) no-repeat center;  width: 100%; padding: 30px 0; margin-bottom: 15px; }
#nav ul li .Multimedia { background: url(); float: left; width: 100%; }
#nav ul li .Documentos { background: url(); float: left; width: 100%; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w27La83z/3/

Comment: Obrigado, Dá para colocar o tamanho dos botoes mais pequenos? E as imagem que tenho no webmail e contactos ja nao aparecem